# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: excel, oracle11g, ado, vba

I write some VBA code in my spreadsheet in excel 2013, the code will connect Oracle 11g to write some data into it. I use following code to connect remote Oracle server:

```
Private Function open_DB(tnsInfo As String, userName As String, pwd As String) As ADODB.Connection
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim connStr As String
    Dim tnsInfoArr As Variant

    tnsInfoArr = getTnsProperty(tnsInfo, ";")

    On Error GoTo Error_Handling
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    'connStr =
    connStr = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
                 "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
                 "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
                 "(HOST=" & tnsInfoArr(1) & ")(PORT=" & tnsInfoArr(2) & "))" & _
                 "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & tnsInfoArr(0) & "))); uid=" & userName & " ;pwd=" & pwd & ";"
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    conn.Open
    conn.CommandTimeout = 120
    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
        'MsgBox "connect to Oracle successfully"
        'conn.Close
    End If
    Set open_DB = conn
End Function
```

this code works fine in my computer but it doesn't work in my colleague's PC, following error messages displayed in my colleague's machine:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified
ADO error #:-2147467259
...
do my colleague need some configuration on his PC? but I remember that I have not configure something in my own computer.
can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?
My OS version is 64-bit windows 7 enterprise edition SP1
and I use MS Office 2013 64-bit edition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up the **user** **DSN** via *ODBC Data Source Admin (32 bit/64 bit)*. Also be sure that your colleague's PC has all drivers you need to run the code.

Cheers.